# Type-based templating function in C++

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, differentiation

I want to write a function that fail-safe accesses `std::map`.

At many places in my code I want to access a `std::map` by key, but in case the key does not exist, I want to have a kind of default value instead of an exception (which is a lot of code for "nothing").

I wrote this template based function

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T2 mapGetByKey(std::map<T1, T2>& map, T1 key, T2 defaultValue={})
{
    auto it = map.find(key);

    if (it != map.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }

    return defaultValue;
};
```

It works great. But for a `std::map<int, const char*>` I would like to have a different behaviour. So I could add this specialization:

```
template <typename T1>
const char* mapGetByKey(std::map<T1, const char*>& map, T1 key, const char* defaultValue="")
{
    auto it = map.find(key);

    if (it != map.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }

    return defaultValue;
};
```

It works, too. But I think it's a lof of code for just one case.

Does anybody have an idea how to save lines without settings the defaultValue to `""` for calls on `std::map<int, const char*>`?

Is there a way to have differentiate between types at compile time, maybe with some `ifdef` or something like that?

Comment: Put the implementation in a third function (without defaults) and call that from the existing templates

Comment: did you think about setting an abstract map value struct that wrap your result ? you can then make the difference between the default and result value .

Answer (score 4):

#### Option #1

```
template <typename T>
T defaultValue()
{
    return {};
}

template <>
const char* defaultValue<const char*>()
{
    return "default string";
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
T2 mapGetByKey(std::map<T1, T2>& map, const T1& key)
{
    auto it = map.find(key);

    if (it != map.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }

    return defaultValue<T2>();
}
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4deeec467c7ea48)

#### Option #2

```
template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
T2 mapGetByKey(std::map<T1, T2>& map, T1 key, const typename identity<T2>::type& defaultValue = {})
{
    auto it = map.find(key);

    if (it != map.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }

    return defaultValue;
}

template <typename T1>
const char* mapGetByKey(std::map<T1, const char*>& map, const T1& key)
{
    return mapGetByKey(map, key, "default string");
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36283ff470103a8d)

Comment: Version 2 sounds and seems good, but when trying to add a 3rd parameter for defaultValue it will run into an infinite loop (because it calls itself instead of the general version).

Comment: @SchubiDuah if you add a default value, overload resolution picks the first version, and you don't even want the second one to be called

Comment: be aware that map doesn't always have two template parameters, it could have more, and when it does, both of your examples fail

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much! I did not see this simple but very effective possibilites.

Combining the two methods while adding the functionality of situation based different defaultValue I did finnally do this:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T mapGetByKeyDefaultValue()
{
    return {};
};

template <>
constexpr const char* mapGetByKeyDefaultValue<const char*>()
{
    return "";
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
T2 mapGetByKey(std::map<T1, T2>& map, T1 key, T2 defaultValue=mapGetByKeyDefaultValue<T2>())
{
    auto it = map.find(key);

    if (it != map.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    };

    return defaultValue;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a template function for the default value, and add its specialized version for the specific type:

```
template <typename T>
T default_value() { return {}; }
template <>
const char* default_value<const char*>() { return ""; }
```

And then

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T2 mapGetByKey(std::map<T1, T2>& map, T1 key, T2 defaultValue=default_value<T2>())
```

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/5R578S)

Comment: `constexpr` is not required by the way.

Comment: @Jarod42 I thought the default value should be a compile-time issue, where am I wrong?

Comment: Default value may be (the result of) a regular function (and it is called each time). [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/74xuhz)

Comment: @Jarod42 So it's definitely a runtime issue...Thanks.